# Value unchanged recursive lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

Why does the below lambda recursion only print 1?
It should minus 1 from its' value and print that value.

```
def p(t):
    print(t)
    while t:
        print(t)
z = lambda x:1 if x == 0 else z(x-1)
p(z(100))
```

Comment: Because the value of z(100) is 1.

Comment: Without some explanation of what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to say what you should do instead.  The simple answer is: forget about recursion, forget about lambda, and just print the numbers 100 down to 1 in a loop in a single function.  If you have some reason for not doing that you need to explain what your goals are.

Answer (score 6):

When you call `p(z(100))`, you pass `z(100)` as the argument.  This means `z` runs to completion before `p` ever begins.  `z` does all its recursing "silently" (because it doesn't print anything itself) and all `p` sees is the `1` that is returned at the very end.

If you want to have each recursion printed, you'd need to include the printing inside the function that is recursing.

Comment: @MatthewduPlessis: I don't think that is a good idea, because each call to `p` will still only ever see one value, so the `while t` will be an infinite loop.

Comment: @MatthewduPlessis, make it into a normal function and `print x`

Answer (score 1):

The only value your lambda can ever return is one.

Comment: How would I return the value to the lambda using the else statement?

Comment: Try instead using something like (just to show you what the difference is) `z = lambda x:1 if x == 0 else x + z(x-1)` - that should show you the way you need to go.